# bash - how to < redirect input, then > redirect output to file

Tags: bash, redirect

So I'm trying this command on Bash:

```
sqlite3 my_db <<!
    .header on
    .mode csv
    select * from table;
!
```

It works, but I want to redirect that output to `output.csv`.

```
sqlite3 my_db <<!
    .header on
    .mode csv
    select * from table;
! > output.csv
```

...but bash seems to think I'm not done with the command:

```
...
$ >
$ >
$ > ^C
$
```

What does Bash want from me?  Why can't I get it to redirect the output to my .csv file?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
sqlite3 my_db <<!  > output.csv
    .header on
    .mode csv
    select * from table;
!
```

Your last line should contain only the ending characters.

Comment: How does bash know not to include `> output.csv` as part of the input being redirected?

Comment: Sorry if that's a really broad question

Comment: If you wanted > output.csv to be part of the input redirected, you would need to escape it like below : sqlite3 my_db <<!  \> output.csv (bash would use > as redirection except if escaped)

Comment: I like this answer because it preserves the order of input redirection, then output redirection (at least syntactically, even if that's not what Bash does internally)

Answer (score 3):

Bash doesn't grossly care what order redirections are specified in if each uses a different FD.

```
sqlite3 my_db > output.csv <<!
 ...
!
```

Comment: That's so confusing. It looks like the input is redirected to the `output.csv` file itself!

Comment: You just need to get used to how the redirection operators work. You can't redirect one file to another in any case; they always apply to the current command. You could even write `> output.cv <<! sqlite3 my_db` if you wanted to.